# Restrict labeling to one label for MultiPolygon features

Tags: openlayers-3

Default labeling in OpenLayers 3.10.1 labels each part of a MultiPolygon.  I want to know if it is possible to label only the first polygon in the MultiPolygon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a separate style for the label with a [geometry function](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.style.html#.GeometryFunction), which returns a single point for the label position.

```
var styles = [
  // Style for the label
  new ol.style.Style({
    text: new ol.style.Text({..}),
    geometry: function(feature) {
        // expecting a MultiPolygon here
        var interiorPoints = feature.getGeometry().getInteriorPoints();
        return interiorPoints.getPoint(0);
    }
  }),
  // Style for the polygons
  new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({...}),
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({...})
  })
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p0acpbtg/2/

Comment: Just great! `+1` ... SO doesn't like `+1`.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Awesome.

Comment: Doesn't quite work for me. It centres on one of the polygons within the multipolygon. If I change it to `return interiorPoints.getPoint(1);` it centres on the other polygon. How do I get it to center on the multipolygon as a whole?

Comment: Yes, right. It centers on the interior point of the first polygon. But you could calculate the convex hull of all polygons (using JSTS or Turf.js) and then take the interior point of that polygon. Or take the mid-point of the extent of the multi-polygon.

Comment: Works for my use. Thanks.